# How to put all selected values of dataset on a simple Report?

Tags: c#

I'm using C# to create a project in which I'm using the dataset to store my data. My question is : how can I add the selected items on dataset so when user click "add to cart button", the selected information of the product go to the final Billing page.. I'm using the datagridview to so the dataset data... Add, delete, update button are also used.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You can see the image by clicking the description

Comment: Use the selected Row event on DGV to get the index of the row.  The index of the DGV is the same as the index in the DataTable.  It is not necessary in this case to use a dataset instead of a datatable.  When querying a database you always get only one datatable.  Not sure why Microsoft allows dataset.  Since you have a dataset then the results should be in ds.Tables[0].